# "TypeError: writer.writerow() takes exactly one argument (3 given)"

Tags: python, csv

Every time the game switches to "gameover-mode" a line should be added to the scoreboard.csv file. I wrote a funtion to do this, but I keep getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Timo\PycharmProjects\2DFlugzeugspiel\main.py", line 208, in <module>
    scoreboard_write()
  File "C:\Users\Timo\PycharmProjects\2DFlugzeugspiel\main.py", line 93, in scoreboard_write
    writer.writerow(current_player, score, date)
TypeError: writer.writerow() takes exactly one argument (3 given)
```

Otherwise the program works perfectly fine and there are no errors.

```
def scoreboard_write():
    from datetime import date # Import module for date

    today = date.today()
    date = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    with open ("scoreboard.csv", "a", newline="") as scoreboard: # Open scoreboard.csv
        writer = csv.writer(scoreboard)
        writer.writerow(current_player, score, date)
...
# Gameover screen
            while running == 3:
                scoreboard_write()
                gameover = False
```

The variable `current_player` is a string, the `score` is an integer.

Comment: The answer is in the stack trace (it generally is). writerow takes only one argument and you have given three. Just combine the three arguments into a list: `writerow([current_player, score, date])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
writer.writerow(current_player, score, date)
```

to

```
writer.writerow([current_player, score, date])
```

and you should be all set. From the [`csv.Writer` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects), "A *row* must be an iterable of strings or numbers for `Writer` objects".